# Copy all Campaigns to another Google Adwords account

Tags: google-adwords

Is it possible to copy all Campaigns from one Google Adwords account to another Google Adwords account including all Ad Groups, Ads, and Keywords?

Answer (score 7):

This should be possible using [Google's AdWords Editor](http://www.google.com/intl/en/adwordseditor/). You can download all content from one account and upload it to the other one. See also [this help page](http://www.google.com/support/adwordseditor/bin/answer.py?answer=38654):

> **Copy and paste campaigns between
>   accounts**
>
> 1. In the tree view, select the account
>      containing the campaigns you want to
>      copy.
> 2. Click the `Campaigns` tab.
> 3. Select
>      one or [more](http://www.google.com/support/adwordseditor/bin/answer.py?answer=30543) campaigns.
> 4. Go to the `Edit
>      Menu > Copy` to copy the campaigns.
> 5. Go
>      to the `File Menu > Open Account`.
> 6. Select the account where you want to
>      paste the campaigns.
> 7. Click `Open
>      Account`
> 8. Select the account name in the
>      tree view.
> 9. Go to the `Edit Menu > Paste`
>      to paste the campaigns.

Note however that statistics will not be copied.